# Set of prime integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers

Let $S$ be a set of primes such that $a,b\in S$ ($a$ and $b$ need not be distinct) implies $ab+4\in S$. Show that $S$ must be empty. (Hint use modulo 7)

I don't have an idea how to use the hint, any further hint will be appreacited

Comment: Hint on using the hint - I haven't tried. What are the possible values of primes mod 7? Multiply each pair and add 4 (mod 7) and look for a contradiction in each case.

Comment: Suppose that $S$ weren't empty and so it contains some element $a$.  Because $a$ is in $S$ so too is $a^2+4$ in $S$... and so too is $(a^2+4)a+4$ in $S$ and so on...  Now, using the hint, can you show why if you were to continue this process you'd wind up with a multiple of $7$ and so wind up with a number which is not prime in $S$, contradicting that $S$ contains only primes?

Comment: Thanks for the hint I will try to use it

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic? I'm not sure how checking modulo $7$ would help. I can think of using modulo $6$ immediately.
Any number, when divided by $6$ leaves a remainder in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$, i.e. any number $n\equiv 1,2,3,4,5,0 \mod 6$. But if $n$ is prime, and $\ge 5$, it can't be $2,3,4$ or $0$ modulo $6$.

Comment: If $a=3$ and $b=5$ then $3\cdot 5+4=19$ is a prime. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ABCD so if $\{3,5,19\} \subseteq S$ then $19\cdot 5+4 \in S$, isn't it?

Comment: @ABCD Nothing, so far. That means that if $3 \in S$ and $5 \in S$, then $19 \in S$. But that can't be the complete set, since it also must include $3 \cdot 19 + 4$, $5 \cdot 19 + 4$, ...

Comment: $5\times19+4$ isn’t prime

Comment: Oh, so that means it's talking about all elements...

Comment: I thought the question was, that if $a,b$ are primes then prove that $ab+4$ cannot be a prime.

Comment: No, it’s asking for proof such a set can’t exist

Comment: @ABCD: No, the problem is to show that there is no non-empty set $S$ f primes with the property that $ab+4\in S$ whenever $a,b\in S$.

Comment: Hint seems straightforward.  We can't have $a,b, ab\equiv 3\pmod 7$ $ab+4 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$ is not prime (unless $ab=3$).  So we cant have $ab\equiv 6\pmod 7$ or $ab\equiv 2\pmod 7$ or $ab\equiv 5\pmod 7$ or .... and so on.... just squish out the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets introduce
$$ r\to s$$
as a shorthand for the statement

> If there is an integer $a\in S$ with $a>1$ and $a\equiv r\pmod 7$, then there exists an integer $b\in S$ with $b>7$ and $b\equiv s\pmod 7$.

Note that $\to $ is transitive, i.e., $r\to s$ and $s\to t$ imply $r\to t$.

If $a\in S$ with $a>1$ and $a\equiv 1\pmod 7$, then we know $b:=a^2+4\in S$. As $b>7$ and $b\equiv 5\pmod 7$, we conclude
$$ 1\to 5.$$
Aditionally, now $S$ must contain $c=ab+4$, which is $\equiv 2\pmod 7$, and finally, $d:=bc+4\in S$ where $d\equiv 0\pmod 7$. So indirectly, we have
$$\tag11\to 0.$$

By simply taking $b=a^2+4$ for all other remainders modulo $7$ and combining this with $(1)$, we arrive at
$$\begin{matrix}&&&&3& &&&2\\&&&&\downarrow&&&&\downarrow\\0&\to& 4&\to &6&\to &5&\to &1&\to& 0\end{matrix}$$
We conclude that if $S$ contains any integer $>1$, then there exists $a\in S$ with $a>7$ and $a\equiv 0\pmod 7$. But then $a$ is not prime.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing the hints I was able to solve the question. I divided it into cases.

case 1: if $b\in\left\{\left.2,5\right\}\right.$ then $b^2+4\equiv1\ mod\ 7$

case 2: if $b\in\left\{\left.0\right\}\right.$ then $b^2+4\equiv4\ mod\ 7$

case 3: if $b\in\left\{\left.1,6\right\}\right.$ then $b^2+4\equiv5\ mod\ 7$

case 4: if $b\in\left\{\left.3,4\right\}\right.$ then $b^2+4\equiv6\ mod\ 7$

It can be shown that by doing, reapted step case $1,2,3$ can be converted into case 4.

for example case $2$: note that ${{(b}^2+4)}^2+4$ is in set $S$ and it equivalnt to  $6 \ mod\ 7 $
and ${{((b}^2+4)}^2+4)(b^2+4)+4$ is also in set S and equivalnt to  $5 \ mod\ 7 $, finally multiplying $6*5+4\equiv6 \mod\ 7$.

So the problem will be equivelant to show that $a\equiv6\ mod\ 7$ for all $a\in\ S$, by using the $ab+4\in\ S$ repeatedly it can be shown that $a\equiv0 \mod\ 7$ thus $7$ divides an element in $S$. which is contridiction. So the set $S$ must be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $p \in S$.

Suppose $p\equiv 1 \pmod 7$ and $p\in S$.  Then $p_2=p^2 +4 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$ is prime and in $S$.  so $p_3 =p_1p_2 + 4\equiv 9\equiv 2\pmod 7$.  So $p_4 = p_3p_2 +4\equiv 2*5+4 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$ is in $S$.  But $7|p_4$ and $p_4$ is prime so $p_4 = p_3p_2 + 4 =7$ so $p_3p_2=3$ but $3$ is primes so that's impossible as $p_3p_2$ are prime so neither are equal to $1$.

So $S$ contains no primes $\pmod 1 \pmod 7$.

suppose $p\equiv 2\pmod 7$.  Then $p_2 = p^2 +4 \equiv 8 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$ which we proved is impossible..

Suppose $p \equiv 3\pmod 7$ then $p_2 = p^2 + 4\equiv 6\pmod 7$.  Then $p_3=pp_2 + 4\equiv 18\equiv 4\pmod 7$.  And $pp_3 + 4\equiv 16 \equiv 2\pmod 7$ which was impossible.

Suppose $p\equiv 4 \pmod 7$. Then $p_2= p^2+4 \equiv 6$ And $p_3=pp_2 + 4 \equiv 28\equiv 0$ so $7|p_3$ so $p_3$ (which is prime) is equal to $7$ and $pp_2 \equiv 3 \pmod 7$ which was impossible two paragraphs up and is still impossible.

Suppose $p\equiv 5 \pmod 7$ then $p_2=p^2 + 4\equiv 29 \equiv 1$.  That's out.

Suppose $p \equiv 6 \pmod 7$ then $p_2 = p^2 + 4 \equiv 5\pmod 7$.  Nope.

So that only leaves $p\equiv 0 \pmod 7$ and as $p$ prime then $7$ is the only element in $S$.  But $7^2 + 4 =53\in S$ which is a contradiction.

so $S$ is empty.